# Bootswatch theme doesnt submit form data

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, forms

I have the lumen theme from bootswatch... everything seems to be working fine except that my form never submits any data ... it goes to the action page but never send any data across... he is the complete code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Some Title
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
<body>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1 id="container">Some Heading</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="bs-component">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Incident Management System</h1>
                <p> Some heading</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Submit a ticket</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="insertForm" method="post" action="addincident.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>We need few details!</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUserName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUserName" placeholder="Enter your username">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputstudentID" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Student ID</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputStudentID" placeholder="Enter your Student ID">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputStudentEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Student EMail</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputStudentEMail" placeholder="Enter your Student Email ID">
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectRoomNo" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Room Number</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectRoomNo">
          <option>S114D</option>
          <option>S118B</option>
          <option>S118E</option>
          <option>S120</option>
          <option>S114B</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textAreaRoomPosition" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Location of machine</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textAreaRoomPosition"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block">Explain to the best of your knowledge the location of the issue in the lab.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textAreaRoomPosition" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Issue\Incident</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textAreaRoomPosition"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block">Explain to the best of your knowledge the issue you are facing. Try to be as detailed as possible.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Information</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Upon recieving the ticket, we will assign it to a designated technician who will then solve the case. You can view the solution of the incident once it is posted.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you name your inputs with the parameters names? Instead of id="inputUserName", write name="inputUserName", or whatever you're expecting on that POST

Comment: I knew I was doing something stupid !!! Thanks!

Comment: No problem ^^ Gonna answer to close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's missing the "name" attribute;

change this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputUserName">
```

to something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="inputUserName" id="inputUserName">
```